# Razor Pages Default Page in aspnetcore 2

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

By default a Razor Page app goes to Home/Index

Is there a way to change this to Home/App?

This is quite easy in MVC, but Razor pages using a different routing setup and thus MVC routing does not apply.

I would think it would be in options somewhere, but I don't see it:

```
services.AddMvc()
            .AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
                options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
                options. ??SetDefaultPage??
            });
```

I have tried this:

`options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/App", "");`

But now two default routes are found and an error is generated:

> AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:
>
> Page: /App
>
> Page: /Index

It's possible to resolve this error by removing Pages/Index.cshtml from the project, but I wanted to keep that page as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pretty sure it isn't possible. The docs say the runtime controls the search for `Index` as the default. I couldn't find where that happens in the current release, but `IndexFileName` is a `static` in the new internal [`PageRouteModelFactory`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/f0ae0ce5280db411b7e0ea802312464d9db4438f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/Internal/PageRouteModelFactory.cs#L16) class added to the upcoming release:

`private static readonly string IndexFileName = "Index" + RazorViewEngine.ViewExtension;`

It doesn't seem like it would be difficult to just add a config property to [`RazorPagesOptions`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/f0ae0ce5280db411b7e0ea802312464d9db4438f/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages/RazorPagesOptions.cs), though. The ASP.NET guys are pretty responsive, I'd open a request as a GitHub issue and hope for the best.

Comment: Ok, thank you for confirming this for me. I will post GitHub issue.

Comment: Had an idea last night --you might be able to use URL rewriting to make it _appear_ that Index resolves to App...

Answer (score 5):

In my case the ambiguity was caused by `Pages/Index.cshtml` left in project.
This worked:

1. `options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/App", "");`
2. remove or rename `Pages/Index.cshtml`

Comment: It's unfortunate step 2 is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by using [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Rewrite/):

Then adding code to replace the default Index action, in my case with Portfolio:

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
    .AddRedirect("^", "portfolio"); // Replace default index page with portfolio
```

More detailed article about rewrite options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?tabs=aspnetcore2x

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to simply redirect from the Index OnGet method, like so:

```
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return Redirect("/Welcome");
        }
    }
```

Notice that I have change the return type of the OnGet method.