# Changing default page in ASP.Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-5

Related Topics:

[Setting a new landing page in ASP.NET Core MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662242/setting-a-new-landing-page-in-asp-net-core-mvc)

[Razor Pages Default Page in aspnetcore 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48684461/razor-pages-default-page-in-aspnetcore-2)

In simplest way, I create a new Asp.net razor page project and Create a folder named 'Identity' and two Razor pages like this:

[image]

and change Route for `TaskSelection` page like this:

[image]

Now I want to change first landing page of this web project and I don't want to:

1. Delete index page
2. Redirect from index page when `Get` method called

I wrote this code in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/TaskSelecttion", "/Identity/TaskSelecttion");
});
```

but it returns to index page!!!.

How can I change default landing page from index to `TaskSelection` page?

Thanks

Comment: What is the url you testing with?

Comment: When you do options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/TaskSelection", "x") , localhost:port/x will take you to Identity/TaskSelection.cshtml. You can setup it up like options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/TaskSelection", "") so that when you enter localhost:port/ you get Identity/TaskSelection.cshtml as the default page.

Comment: @mxmissile I just run the project and the url is `https://localhost/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the `options` like this:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/Identity/TaskSelection", "");
});
```

but I got this error:

> AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:
> /Identity/TaskSelection
> /Index

so I change the routing for index page like this:

[image]

and it worked